# How to add some code inside the JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript

Enviroment: Visual Studio 2012, MVC4, Razor, Internet Application.

I have a JavaScript array..

```
var over100 = "@Model.Over100";
var filterarray = [
{
    "name": "Condition",
    "value": "New",
    "paramName": "",
    "paramValue": ""
},
{
    "name": "FreeShippingOnly",
    "value": "false",
    "paramName": "Currency",
    "paramValue": "USD"
},
    ];
```

In case of... `if(over100 != null)`

I want...

```
var filterarray = [
{
    "name": "Condition",
    "value": "New",
    "paramName": "",
    "paramValue": ""
},
{
    "name": "FreeShippingOnly",
    "value": "false",
    "paramName": "Currency",
    "paramValue": "USD"
},
{ 
    "name": "Over100",
    "value": "true",
    "paramName": "",
    "paramValue": ""
},
    ];
```

I would like to know all the possible ways, how to do that.

Thank You!

Comment: This cannot be done *inside* an array literal. It could be done easily using `Array.push` (or the similar `arr[arr.length] = newVal` idiom).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `push()`:

```
if(over100 != ''){
    var addfilter = {"name": "Over100",
        "value": "true",
        "paramName": "",
        "paramValue": ""}

    filterarray.push(addfilter)
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add as a filter just the code from a variable? For example use a var "over100" as filter?

Comment: Probably want to declare `addfilter` as a local variable or write the code without the need for a local variable at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(over100 != null) {
    filterarray.push({"name": "Over100", "value": "true", "paramName": "", "paramValue": ""})
}
```

Comment: Thank You! (Same as Mihai Iorga. Works.)